# Trouble with methods from one class interacting with methods in another class

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

i am a high school student in an AP Computer Science course, and over the weekend we were assigned this project:

*"Simulate the wandering of an intoxicated person in a square street grid. Draw a grid of 10 streets horizontally and 10 streets vertically. Represent the simulated drunkard by a dot, placed in the middle of the grid to start. For 100 times, have the simulated drunkard randomly pick a direction (east, west, north, south), move one block in the chosen direction, and draw the dot. After the iterations, display the distance that the drunkard has covered. (One might expect that on average the person might not get anywhere because the moves to different directions cancel one another out in the long run, but in fact it can be shown with probability 1 that the person eventually moves outside any finite region."*

However, because graphics are not part of the curriculum, the grid is simulated by a grid created by a loop in a Grid class, and the dot representing the drunkard is an X, such as :

[image: example of grid]

The default position for the X is at (5,5) which is shown above. However, I am having trouble with getting the X to move randomly.

My Drunkard class

```
public class Drunkard 
{

int row;

int column;

public Drunkard()
{
    row = 5;
    column = 5;
}

public int getCol()
{
    return column;
}

public int getRow()
{        
    return row;
}

public void moveRandomly()
{
    double directionDeterminer = Math.random();

    if (directionDeterminer >= 0 && directionDeterminer <= 0.25) 
    {
        row++;

    }
    else if (directionDeterminer >= 0.25 && directionDeterminer <= 0.50)
    {
        row--;

    }
    else if ( directionDeterminer >= 0.50 && directionDeterminer <= 0.75)
    {
        column++;

    }
    else if ( directionDeterminer >= 0.75 && directionDeterminer <= 1.00)
    {
        column--;

    }
}
```

}

and my grid class (Which contains the loop for creating the grid):

```
public class Grid
{

    public static final int MAX_NUM_ROWS = 10;

    public static final int MAX_NUM_COLUMNS = 10;

    public Grid()
    {

    }

    public void draw(Drunkard theDrunk)
    {
        Drunkard drunk = new Drunkard();
        drunk.getRow();
        int y = drunk.getCol();

        String newRow = "- - - - - - - - - - ";
        drunk.moveRandomly();

        for (int row = 0; row < MAX_NUM_ROWS - 1; row++)
        {

            if (row == 4)
            {
                y = 8;
                System.out.print( newRow.substring(0,y) + "X " + newRow.substring(10,20) );
                System.out.print("\n");


            }

            for (int column = 0; column < MAX_NUM_COLUMNS ; column++)
            {
                System.out.print("- ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The method moveRandomly() is supposed to either increment or decrement the rows or columns so that the position of the X changes either north, south, east or west. However, i am unsure on how to have the variables from moveRandomly() (row and column) have any effect on the grid created in the Grid class. Does anyone have an idea on how to make it so the variables have an effect on the grid? Keep in mind that I am a beginning programmer, so I have basic knowledge on loops and if statements, not arrrays or graphics. Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this `public void draw(Drunkard theDrunk) { Drunkard drunk = new Drunkard();`? How many `Drunkard`(s) do you want?

Comment: I created that in the hopes that I could use the methods of the Drunkard class within Grid. I only want 1 drunkard, though.

Comment: Then just use `theDrunk` you passed to draw...

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty good, i think you might just want something like this in draw:

```
for(int row = 0; row < MAX_NUM_ROWS - 1; row ++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < MAX_NUM_COLUMNS - 1; column ++)
    {
       if((row == theDrunk.getRow()) && (column == theDrunk.getCol()))
           System.out.print("X");
       else
           System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This could also be done with substring given some modification

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem I see when I try that is that the X does not start at the default position of (5,5) and it seems to only move to the right, not the left. Would it be possible to somehow add an if statement to this so that the first time the grid is looped it starts at (5,5) and move from there?

Comment: When the drunk is created: the Constructor of the Drunkard class, the values for row and column are set to 5. They probably should be set to 4 because the rows start at 0 and not 1.

Comment: Thanks once again. One other question, is it ever possible for the X to go off of the grid in this situation? I remember my instructor showed us an example of it going off the grid but still moving, so that it could still move back into the grid. Is it a coincidence that the X isn't moving, or is there also something wrong with the code?

Comment: yes it could. The moveRandomly method has no boundries so it should be able to move the drunk outside of the grid. I would assume it is a coincidence.